# Reduce lists using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm looking for some functionality in python for doing the following:

```
x = [1, 2 ,3]
y = [1, 3, 4 ,5]

z = x - y
print "result: " + z
--------------------------
```

result [2]

This is similar to van diagram reduction operation on groups.
Any idea how can I achieve this using some operator?

Comment: It looks like you want set operations: `list(set(x) - set(y)) == [2]`. Not sure if order matters to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a list comprehension in O(n^2)

```
z = [xi for xi in x if xi not in y]
```

or using `set` for hashable objects which runs in O(n)

```
z = list(set(x) - set(y))
```

Comment: Can you please explain why complexity is better in seconds solution?

Comment: "Obvoiously" the operations `list(...)` and `set(...)` are O(n), further `set - set` is O(n), so we get O(n) in total. Basically the code is equivalent to `yset = set(y)`, `z = [xi for xi in x if xi not in yset]`, where `xi in yset` is O(1) using a hash table.